# Timeout occured because the target machine actively refused it when writing to MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to write some data to Mongo DB that is hosted on Azure. For this I've created a Cosmos DB account with the API *"Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB API"*.

To write my data I use this code using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and C#.

```cs
string connectionString = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&appname=@<region>";
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));

settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings()
{
    EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
};

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseId); // `DatabaseId` is a `string`.
IMongoCollection<TEntity> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TEntity>(CollectionId); // `CollectionId` is a `string`.
IEnumerable<WriteModel<TEntity>> entitiesToInsert = entities.Select(entity => new InsertOneModel<TEntity>(entity)); // `entities` is an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` where `TEntity` is `class`.

await mongoCollection.BulkWriteAsync(entitiesToInsert); // → Error on this line.
```

But on the last line, I've always this exception. It happens not occasionally and retrying fails too. The database and collection name both exists.

> **`TimeoutException`:** A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using `CompositeServerSelector`.
>
> **`MongoConnectionException`:** An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
>
> **`SocketException`:** No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it x.x.x.x:10255
>
> <sup>[Complete log on pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/hP90hZVv)</sup>

The firewall is configured to allow access from all networks.

Why happens this error and how could I solve this?

**Update:** By adding the database to the connection string and removing the `replicaSet` and `appname`, doesn't solve my problem.

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>?ssl=true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/connect-mongodb-account#connection-string-requirements) you are missing the name of the database in the connection string.
If none is supplied, it uses `test` as the db name.

So try this:

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://xxx:xxx@xxx.documents.azure.com:10255/yourdatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&appname=@West Europe";
```